# css not applying while creating PDF using itextsharp.xmlworker.dll

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, pdf-generation

I want to Generate PDF, but it's not taking all css which i need, like its not applying Margin, Padding, Align etc. I also want to put image on my PDF but I don't know how? following is my code

```
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
Document doc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER, 10, 10, 42, 35);        
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, memoryStream);
HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(null);

htmlContext.SetTagFactory(Tags.GetHtmlTagProcessorFactory());

//create a cssresolver to apply css
ICSSResolver cssResolver = XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().GetDefaultCssResolver(false);

cssResolver.AddCss("div{color: red; text-align:center; font-size:30px;}", true);
cssResolver.AddCss("h1{color: green;}", true);

//Create and attach pipline, without pipline parser will not work on css
IPipeline pipeline = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, new PdfWriterPipeline(doc, writer)));

//Create XMLWorker and attach a parser to it
XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(pipeline, true);
XMLParser xmlParser = new XMLParser(worker);

//All is well open documnet and start writing.
doc.Open();
string htmltext = "<html><body><h1>This is Heading </h1><div>This is a div content.</div></body></html>";
xmlParser.Parse(new StringReader(htmltext));

//Done! close the documnet
doc.Close();
```

Comment: XMLWorker only supports a limited set of CSS declarations, it's likely a subset of your CSS declarations is not supported and hence is not applied.

Comment: As for the image, have a look at http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/xml-worker-itext5/html-images

Comment: Thanks for ur rply.....i also used HTMLWorker but that is giving same issue, i want to formatted my pdf document. is any other way to fix my issue?

Comment: Yes, with pdfHTML, an add-on for iText 7. See http://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfHTML